# Google Apps as SAML IdP

Tags: google-apps, saml-2.0

I'm trying to configure Google Apps as SAML IdP with Zoho as service provider.
After authentication, the SAML response xml from Google always contains NameID Format as unspecified.

```
<saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">email@company.com</saml2:NameID>
```

Google Apps does have the option to change the NameID Format. Refer this screenshot :
[Service Provider details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87J0h.png)
But even if EMail is selected as NameID Format, the above response is present in SAML Response xml.

The expected NameID Format in response is as follows :

```
<saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">email@company.com</saml2:NameID>
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if Zoho-SP sends `<AuthnRequest />` with Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified" to Google-IdP. If yes, send `<AuthnRequest />` with Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" from Zoho-SP side and try.

Setting NameID format in IdP is for default configuration. That setting won't be taken, if AuthnRequest specify which NameID format to used to identify the user between IdP and SP, upon authentication.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zeigeist. Setting the "Format" attribute in "NameIDPolicy" element worked. If the AuthnRequest does not contain any Format, Google uses "unspecified" by default.